# Tomcat not processing request

Tags: java, multithreading, tomcat

I have a problem with my production tomcat in which my web application is deployed. I runs fine for some long duration but after that whenever any user try to access the application through web browser then connection reset message will be shown on the browser literally application down.

I tried to increase the tomcat memory but the problem still continue. I have taken the thread dump also in which all the thread are showing in BLOCKED state.

Can anyone help me out !!!

Thread dump sample

```
"http-80-173" daemon prio=6 tid=0x55392800 nid=0xf84 waiting for monitor entry [0x64c8e000..0x64c8f9e8]
   java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:2882)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.expandCapacity(AbstractStringBuilder.java:100)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:572)
    at java.lang.StringBuffer.append(StringBuffer.java:320)
    - locked <0x4472eeb8> (a java.lang.StringBuffer)
    at java.text.MessageFormat.applyPattern(MessageFormat.java:436)
    at java.text.MessageFormat.<init>(MessageFormat.java:350)
    at java.text.MessageFormat.format(MessageFormat.java:811)
    at org.apache.naming.StringManager.getString(StringManager.java:121)
    at org.apache.naming.StringManager.getString(StringManager.java:144)
    at org.apache.naming.resources.FileDirContext.getAttributes(FileDirContext.java:432)
    at org.apache.naming.resources.BaseDirContext.getAttributes(BaseDirContext.java:747)
    at org.apache.naming.resources.ProxyDirContext.cacheLoad(ProxyDirContext.java:1531)
    at org.apache.naming.resources.ProxyDirContext.cacheLookup(ProxyDirContext.java:1454)
    at org.apache.naming.resources.ProxyDirContext.lookup(ProxyDirContext.java:288)
    at org.apache.naming.resources.DirContextURLConnection.getInputStream(DirContextURLConnection.java:368)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.isOutDated(Compiler.java:435)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.isOutDated(Compiler.java:392)
```

All thread will be in same state.

```
"http-80-160" daemon prio=6 tid=0x5538dc00 nid=0x1e80 waiting for monitor entry [0x6453e000..0x6453fce8]
   java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.<init>(AbstractStringBuilder.java:45)
    at java.lang.StringBuffer.<init>(StringBuffer.java:79)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLCollation.readCollation(Unknown Source)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TypeInfo.init(Unknown Source)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.StreamColumns.processBytes(Unknown Source)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.IOBuffer.processPackets(Unknown Source)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(Unknown Source)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.doExecuteStatement(Unknown Source)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement$StatementExecutionRequest.executeStatement(Unknown Source)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.CancelableRequest.execute(Unknown Source)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeRequest(Unknown Source)
    **- locked <0x444b72c0> (a com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSWriter)**
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeQuery(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingStatement.java:208)
```

Also this is a common line i am getting in most of the cases:

- locked <0x444b72c0> (a com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSWriter)

I am using JDBC driver 2 and my Operating system is Windows 2007

Also i am using connection pooling and during getting the connection it is showing locked

```
"http-80-172" daemon prio=6 tid=0x55392400 nid=0x2548 waiting for monitor entry [0x64bfe000..0x64bffa68]
   java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool.getNumIdle(GenericObjectPool.java:911)
    - waiting to lock <0x3ef89f88> (a org.apache.commons.dbcp.AbandonedObjectPool)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.AbandonedObjectPool.borrowObject(AbandonedObjectPool.java:78)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDriver.connect(PoolingDriver.java:176)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:582)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:207)
    at com.cong.vts.dbutil.JDBCConnection.getConnection(JDBCConnection.java:42)
    at com.cong.vts.dbutil.SQLFunctions.createCSSFile(SQLFunctions.java:10069)
```

Comment: What is the Operating System of your prod environment? And please share catalina.out log files and a sample from your ThreadDump ?

Comment: Looks like a deadlock... Your thread dump should tell you at what point in your (or a library's) code your are stuck, and who owns the locks that matter. This is certainly crucial to understand your issue, or help others indentify it.

Comment: I have edited the question in which you can see the dump

Comment: You can check this link also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28606811/out-of-memory-tomcat-unable-to-create-new-native-thread this issue is not coming now my thread count is less the 350 now but application goes down